# Initializing array creates a nil object?

Tags: arrays, ruby, null

I am creating a new

```
@array = Array.new
```

I subsequently want to use a function that pushes an element onto the array

```
@array << object
```

But I get a

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass
```

error.

Can someone help me understand this behavior?

Here's some code in context

```
class Hand #abstract
@values_of_cards = Hash.new()
@cards_in_hand = ['']
@hand_size = 0
@minmax = @values_of_cards.minmax {|a, b| a.value <=> b.value}

def add_card(card)
  if @cards_in_hand == nil || (@cards_in_hand.length < @hand_size && !contains?(card))
   @cards_in_hand.push(card)
  end
end
```

Here 'card' is an object defined in a separate class.

Comment: Where are those lines called? Can you provide some more context? The snippets you posted should be perfectly fine if written one after another

Comment: @PatrickOscity I added the code in question

Comment: contains? is not defined! Did you mean @cards_in_hand.include? instead?

Comment: @SlySherZ contains is defined further down in the code :)

Comment: if @cards_in_hand == nil . Should this be != ?

Comment: @Mircea oh no, that was my way of fixing another nil error that it gave for cards_in_hand.length!

Comment: Just write print @cards_in_hand at the start at the start of the add_card function and check whether or not it's value is what you expected it to be at each point in the program.

Answer (score 3):

```
class MyClass
  @some_variable
  def some_method
    @some_variable
  end
end
```

`@some_variable` on line 2 refers to a *class* instance variable, while `@some_variable` on line 4 refers to an instance variable. They are *completely* *different*.  Instance variables accessed in the context of the class itself are called class instance variables.  Instance variables accessed in the context of an instance method are just regular instance variables.

The first four lines in your class are setting *class* instance variables, which are *completely* *different* than *regular* instance variables

It looks like you are *trying* to set initial values for several instance variables. To do that, you need to wrap the first four lines in the `initialize` method like this:

```
def initialize
  @values_of_cards = Hash.new()
  @cards_in_hand = ['']
  @hand_size = 0
  @minmax = @values_of_cards.minmax {|a, b| a.value <=> b.value}
end
```

Note: as-written the last line there for `@minmax` is operating on a Hash with no elements, so it's not really doing much.  If the hash *did* have elements, the `minmax` code would fail for reasons beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for that! Good to know the things, only starting out with Ruby, but I still get the same error T.T

Comment: @scy The code you posted doesn't have an array or a `push`, so my answer assumes you had a different version of your code where you were defining an Array as a class instance variable and then trying to push onto it in an instance method, where the instance variable would actually be `nil` since it wasn't initialized.   If your circumstances are different than that, and fixing the issue with initializing your variables properly doesn't solve it, please post a new question with the exact code that's failing and the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the variables from @variable to @@variable